# Editor, UiBinder and automatic mapping from Integer to String

Tags: gwt

I have a basic object which has 3 attributes :

- id : Integer
- width : Integer
- height : Integer

I need an editor to make **height** and **width** editable and I also want to display the **id** in a **Label**.

The problem is that the **Label** accepts a String whereas the **id** is an Integer. So if I try the following :

```
  @UiField
  Label id;
```

I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Line 17: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to String
```

I can solve this problem with the following code:

```
@UiField
@Ignore
Label myId;

...

void setId(Integer id){
    this.myId.setText(""+id);
}
```

but it means that I have to manually call setId() when I edit() the editor.

Is there a way to have the text of the label automatically updated when the id is set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`NumberLabel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/NumberLabel.html) rather than a `Label`.

Comment: Once again you rock Thomas